# Migrate the wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, config

I have a wordpress site with some my edits. I need to remove it from **www.firstserver.sk** to **www.secondserver.sk**
Is there any manner to do that? I thought It should be enough, If I copy the whole FTP and the database and change information in `wp_config.php`

Comment: I highly recommend the [WordPress Duplicator Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/). It GREATLY simplifies the process of migrating a site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move WordPress to a new server or to a different location on your server, you do not need to reinstall. WordPress can handle this situation. Please refer this link for more info. http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward. You need to ensure that:

1. You copy all your files via FTP
2. Update the info in `wp-config.php`
3. Import your database
4. IMPORTANT: Update your database as your URLs will now be different.

These steps are covered in more detail [in this article](http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.

First of all make Database in **www.secondserver.sk** .Name should be same so you won't find any difficulty.

2)Change `siteurl` and `homeurl` from **wp_option** table in the database of **www.fisrtserver.sk**. Export database from **www.fisrtserver.sk** and import it in **www.secondserver.sk**.

3)Also upload everything through FTP to new location.

Also Add in wp-config.php Define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-site-url.com'); Define('WP_HOME','http://your-site-url.com');

Second Option :

You can use [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin as well.

Answer (score -1):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/  Download and install this plugin on server 1, active the plugin select it from the menu, run through the steps.

You will get 2 files, an installer and a file zip. upload both to server 2. go to http://yoursite.co.uk/installer.php and run through the steps

Bingo site has moved.